# MySql: IN query not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, filter

I have a table **ocmsreservenow** like below,

```
+-----------------+
| cmsreservenowid |
+-----------------+
|               1 |
|               2 |
|               3 |
|               4 |
|               5 |
|               7 |
|               8 |
|               6 |
|               9 |
+-----------------+
```

when am writing query to select some values,

```
select 
    cmsreservenowid
from
    ocmsreservenow
where
    cmsreservenowid in (1 , 1, 2);
```

it yields output like

```
 +-----------------+
 | cmsreservenowid |
 +-----------------+
 |               1 |
 |               2 |
 +-----------------+
```

what am expecting is

```
 +-----------------+
 | cmsreservenowid |
 +-----------------+
 |               1 |
 |               1 |
 |               2 |
 +-----------------+
```

please clarify me why it is not yielding output that I expected?

Comment: There's only one 1 row to return...

Comment: [IN Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) check whether the value of the column is in the specified values.

Comment: Because its thinks like: 'Ok, he gave me 1-9 numbers and i need to return only 1 or 1 or 2, ok its only 2 values that match this condition.' Then u see result

Answer (score 1):

The `where` clause *filters* rows.  It does not *generate* them.  So, for each row in the table, the your `where` clause will check if the `cmsreservenowid` is in the stated list.  If true, then the row is returned; if false (or `NULL`), then the row is not returned.

No opportunity for duplication.

If you want duplication, then you want a `join`: in this case, a `left join`:

```
select ids.id
from (select 1 as id union all select 1 union all select 2
     ) ids left join
     ocmsreservenow o
     on o.cmsreservenowid = ids.id;
```